# determining event.target in as2

Tags: flash, events, actionscript-2, adobe-flash-cs3

How to detect on which movieClip an event has fired in as2. I have made a list of duplicate movieclips and want to add click event on each movieclip and distinguish on which movieclip event has fird. I know the solution in as3 but need as2 solution for it. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS2, when you assigned a function say using `myButton.onRelease = myFunction;`, within the function you can reference the caller simply using `this`:

```
function myFunction() {
 trace(this._name);
}

myButton.onRelease = myFunction; // will trace "myButton" when you click it
```